# C# wait for page loading (web browser)

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I am new to C # , so I am sorry if this question is stupid. 
I'm trying to do some automation using web browser winforms control.

to check the download status I use ReadyState:

while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }

i get the value Complete in WebBrowserReadyState but the page does not load completely, as it contains charts.

How to wait for example 2 seconds, , to load all the elements on a web page?
I use windows 10 IE 11.

```html
            using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.Width = width;
                browser.Height = height;
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;

                Uri uri = new Uri(Mon_URL);
                string additionalHeaderInfo = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                browser.Navigate(uri, null, null, additionalHeaderInfo);
                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
             }
            Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> while (**browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete**) {
>   Application.DoEvents(); }
>
> i get the value Complete in WebBrowserReadyState but the page does not
>   load completely, as it contains charts.
>
> How to wait for example 2 seconds, , to load all the elements on a web
>   page? I use windows 10 IE 11.

Please check the condition. The [WebBrowserReadyState.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate?view=netframework-4.7.2) status means the control has finished loading the new document and all its contents. if you want to wait all elements load success, you could change the condition from "!=" to "==", like this:

```
while (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
Application.DoEvents(); }
```